# PHP - locking an exported file

Tags: php, mysql, csv, passwords, zip

I'm looking for an easiest way to lock a file. The following code export a .csv file from mysql via php code :

```
<?php
require_once('connect_db.php');
$fdate = $_POST['fdate'];
$tdate = $_POST['tdate'];
//Selecting Items based on Date 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT item_no, qty, discount_price, date FROM sold_items WHERE date BETWEEN '".$fdate."' AND '".$tdate."' ORDER BY date Desc");


//Check if File Name Exists
$filename = $name = "C:/Sales-{$tdate}".".csv";
$index = 1;
while(file_exists($filename)) {
  $filename = $name.'--'.$index.".csv";
  $index++;
}

//Fputs the Table Headers
fputcsv($f, array('Item No', 'Qty', 'Sell Price', 'Date'));

//Fputcsv adds records to csv file
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM))
{
    fputcsv($f, $row);
}

//Close file
fclose($f);

?>
```

All i need know is a code that will do any of the following:

- Password protect .csv file when trying to open it
- locking fields which makes this file uneditable
- or convert this .csv file to zip file, and create password before extracting it.

I'm not looking for high secured way to lock this file. However while googling around I found this code :

```
<?php echo system('zip -P pass file.zip file.txt'); ?>
```

I've tried it! but its not working.

Thank You

---

Edit: Using flock

```
$file = fopen("{$filename}", "w+"); 

// exclusive lock 
if (flock($file,LOCK_EX)){ 
//Fputs the Table Headers
fputcsv($f, array('Item No', 'Qty', 'Sell Price', 'Date'));

//Fputcsv adds records to csv file
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM))
{
    fputcsv($f, $row);
}

  flock($file,LOCK_UN); 
} 
else{ 
  echo "Could not lock file!"; 
} 

fclose($file); 

?>
```

It will export the csv file empty but when trying to write something inside any fields and save it; An error will pop up " filename " is read-only and forces me to save as file to another name. But after saving as the file, you can still edit fields and save it. How to disable save as?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you can change its permission using chmod() function.

You can pass parameter like

0777 which means full permission for read-write same way you can assign by which no one can read or write in file.

Comment: I've did a search for chmod() in PHP manual and found like this chmod("/somedir/somefile", 0777) but i don't know where to place this code. Please help me :(

Comment: I've placed the code after fclose and when testing it, it opens the file but when trying to change values in fields and doing file save; An error shows up that says "filename" is read-only. Which is exactly what i wanted but...It automatically asks to save file as another file name, which later it makes the file fields editable. Is there a way to Not ask for another save as option ?

Comment: It force you to save that file with another name ?

Comment: Exactly it forces to save the file with another name

Comment: Can you please check in another browser

Answer (score 1):

What about the PHP function [flock](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php)? Small example:

```
<?php

$file = fopen("test.txt","w+");

// exclusive lock
if (flock($file,LOCK_EX)){

  //write to file here

  // release lock
  flock($file,LOCK_UN);
}
else{
  echo "Could not lock file!";
}

fclose($file);

?>
```

Comment: I've never tried it, but could you please write down the code. I had a tough time just doing the above code. I'm not really familiar with php files. :(

Comment: @Alihamra One question: Does your code actually work at the moment?

Comment: Yes, my code works perfectly. I will test the code you've provided. Thanks for your time